Can 目印 refer to people?
This is from Full Metal Alchemist: Brotherhood where a main character gets off the train onto the station and thinks to themselves about previous instructions they received:

西口で目印が立ってるから すぐ分かるって言ってたけど.
He said there'd be someone waiting for me at the west gate, and I'd be able to spot him right away, but... (show’s translation)

Certainly, unlike “landmark” which, containing the word “land”, is not used for people, 目印 doesn’t contain a kanji making it exclusive to “landmark” items, but none of my dictionaries say it’s used with people so I wonder if this is a translation liberty of sort.

One of the translations of 目印 is "marker". It can refer to anything that serves as a guide or reference point for orientation. A 目印 is usually a building, a small statue, a mountain, a signboard, or anything that's immobile and eye-catching. Calling a person a 目印 is not typical, and just saying 目印が立ってる would sound a little puzzling at first. You can at least tell it's something/someone that can "stand" (立つ), but you cannot tell if it's a person, a signboard or something else. So, this is more like a "you'll know what I mean" type of statement, said jokingly. (If I remember the scene correctly, the main character will realize the intended meaning of 目印 soon after this, right? A very eye-catching person is waiting for him at the station.)

Yes, eye-catching is certainly one way to describe Major Armstrong and his 筋肉美.
